# Update-Database not updating identity tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to update my database by using automatic migrations. I have recently added some properties to the Identity Model:

```
namespace CISC_Website.Models
{    
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool ConfirmedEmail { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("CISCDb")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

However whenever I run the update-database command these changes are not pushed as my user tables are still the same as when they were first created.

Here is the contents of my migrations folder:

```
namespace CISC_Website.Migrations
{

    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CISC_Website.Models.CISCDb>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(CISC_Website.Models.CISCDb context)
        {
            //seed data...
        }
    }
}
```

I know originally when the enable migrations command was run, the identity model was represented as such:

```
namespace CISC_Website.Models
{    
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {

    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how i can get these tables recognized??

Comment: Have you added a migration? You need to actually add a migration before you run update database. This will generate an upgrad/downgrade scaffold class for that particular change set. Once this is created you can run update-database to apply the changes to your target

Comment: No i have automatic migrations enabled... and it works for the rest of my models....

Comment: In that case try using Add-Migration anyway, it may be that some changes you gave made cannot be automatically scaffolded (not sure what as it looks pretty clear cut from your model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application has two DbContexts: CISCDb and IdentityDbContext and you have configured migrations only for your CISCDb context. Therefore changes in the Identity context are not included in the CISCDb migrations.

You should be able to configure the migrations for the IdentityContext the same way you did for the other context to get it working.